# HTML input output

Tags: javascript, php, html, email, text

User enters their name here as part of a form.

```
  <p>Name <font color="red">(required) </font> <input name="flname" required="required" placeholder="Your Name" </p>
```

This solution currently provides a way of providing a sample text that can also be edited, and the PHP can run inside it, unlike `<textarea>`. However, my problem is that unlike `<textarea>`, I cannot seem to get the `<div contenteditable...` to submit its information to the email php file I have set up on the server. Anyone have any idea how I'd implement this.

```
  <div contenteditable="true" name="message" required="" placeholder="Your Message" >Dear <?php echo "$mptitle $mpsecondname" ?>, <p> Please support us... </p>
 <p> Kind Regards, </p>
 <script type="text/javascript"> document.write(document.getElementById('flname').id);</script>
 </div>
 <div align="center">
```

**# Update 2:**
Hi,

Thank you both for your quick resposnes.

I tried to implement your solution here:

```
    <div align="left">
     <form action="form.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <p>Name <font color="red">(required) </font> <input name="flname"       required="required" placeholder="Your Name" </p>
    <p>Email <font color="red">(required) </font> <input name="emailfrom" type="email" required="required" placeholder="Your Email">  </p>
    <p>Address <font color="red">(required) </font> <input name="address" type="name" required="required" placeholder="Address"> </p>
        <p>City <font color="red">(required) </font> <input name="city" type="name" required="required" placeholder="City"> </p>
        <p>Postcode <font color="red">(required) </font> <input name="postcode" type="name" required="required" placeholder="Postcode"> </p>
               <p>What is 2+2? <font color="red">(required) </font> <input name="human" required placeholder="Type Here">  </p>
        <p> <b> You can edit the text below as much or as little as you wish </b> </p>
          <div contenteditable="true" required="" placeholder="Your              Message" >Dear <?php echo "$mptitle $mpsecondname" ?>, <p> Please support us... </p> <p> Kind Regards, </p>
    </div>
         <input type=hidden name=userContent id=userContent>
        <script>
        var el=document.getElementById('userForm');
        el.addEventListener('submit', function() {
        var elInput=document.getElementById('userContent');
        var elDiv=document.getElementById('divContent');
        elInput.value = elDiv.innerHTML;
        });
        </script>

     <div align="center">
    <input id="cancel" name="cancel" type="submit" value="Cancel" />
        <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

PHP:

```
  <?php
    ini_set('display_errors',1);  error_reporting(E_ALL);
    include('mplookup.php');
    $name = $_POST['flname'];
    $email = $_POST['emailfrom'];
    $message = $_POST['userContent'];
     $address = $_POST['address'];
     $city = $_POST['city'];
     $postcode = $_POST['postcode'];
    $human = $_POST['human'];
    $to = "";
    $body = $message;
    $subject = 'From: $email \r\n : Sisi\'s visit to the UK: Sent using EG4DEMUK\'s Tool ';

    ?>
    <?php
    if ($_POST['submit']) {
        if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $email))
        {
            echo '<p>Thank you for your email!</p>';
        } else {
            echo '<p>Oops! An error occurred. Try sending your message again.</p>';
        }
    }
    ?>
```

However, the emails outputed look like this

```
From: Hassan Ismail
E-Mail: 
Message
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

A `<div>` is not a form element, so it won't be submitted. You need to implement an event listener on the submit event of the form that picks up the content of the `<div>` and puts it in a form element. Add a hidden `<input>` to the form for the purpose.

Here's a simple example:

```
<div id=divContent style="width:400px; height=200px;overflow:auto" contenteditable>Some content</div>
<form id=userForm>
    <input type=hidden name=userContent id=userContent>
        <input type=submit name=submit value="Send!">
</form>


<script>
        var el=document.getElementById('userForm');
el.addEventListener('submit', function() {
    var elInput=document.getElementById('userContent');
    var elDiv=document.getElementById('divContent');
    elInput.value = elDiv.innerHTML;
});

</script>
```

```js
var el=document.getElementById('userForm');
el.addEventListener('submit', function() {
    var elInput=document.getElementById('userContent');
    var elDiv=document.getElementById('divContent');
    elInput.value = elDiv.innerHTML;
});
```

```html
<div id=divContent style="width:400px; height=200px;overflow:auto" contenteditable>Some content</div>
<form id=userForm>
    <input type=hidden name=userContent id=userContent>
        <input type=submit name=submit value="Send!">
</form>
<script>
```

Answer (score -1):

`getElementById('flname')` ... is it clearly written in the name of the method that themethod gets an element by its `Id`, but not by his name. Use `getElementsByName` or set an id to you input tag. your input tag is not closed too ... don't use font - it is obsolete. if you want to submit  tag content, use ajax, or setup a hidden field somwhere in the code, then use submit handler to set it with the content of the div before the actual submit.

```
<div id="yourdivid">....</div>
<input id="submitarea" type="hiden" name="submitarea">

$(function() {
  $('#yourformid').submit( function() {
    $('#submitarea').val($('#yourdivid').html()); 
  }); 
});
```